# NGINX 404 Not Found в файле с русскими и другими отличными английскому символами

Tags: nginx

Есть поддомен сайта сделанный исключительно для загрузки и скачивания файлов на него.

Вот простая конфигурация:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name dl.site.com;


  index index.php;
  root /home/www/dl;

      location ~* {
        add_header Content-disposition "attachment; filename=$1";
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        root /home/www/dl; 
      }
}
```

Собственно всё работает, при заходе на страницу файла идёт его загрузка браузером. Но дело в том что если файл содержит русские символы в названии, или к примеру китайские, то уже при заходе на него происходит ошибка `404 Not Found nginx/1.14.0`.

Update, вот глянул лог:

```
2018/07/18 16:11:06 [error] 12699#12699: *1 open() "/home/www/dl/uploads/2018/07/18/MTc4/наблюдение.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.68.239.154, server: dl.site.com, request: "GET /uploads/2018/07/18/MTc4/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).sf HTTP/1.1", host: "dl.site.com"
```

По логу видно что отличные от английских букв кодируются urlencode. Может быть nginx не правильно кодирует русские символы и не может найти файл таким образом?

Comment: вы не догадались посмотреть в логе, файл с каким именем разыскивает программа *nginx* и сделать выводы о том, почему это имя совсем не соответствует тому, что хотелось бы получить?

Comment: Какой забавный location. Как он вообще работает-то?